# can access virtualhost locally on the same server but cannot access on remote machine

Tags: centos, iptables, virtualhost, remote-access, selinux

A pretty wired problem occured when configure a virtualhost at port 81.

When I use command `curl 123.123.123.123:81` or `curl localhost:81` in the same server, it got response. While when I access it from remote machine either by `curl 123.123.123.123:81` or browser it does not work, showing error connection time out.

I am using centOS 6.3. Note that I have closed iptables and selinux to test it and I am pretty sure they were both closed.

the remote  machine can get access to World Wide Web. Anyone has similar experiences? What happened ?

**iptables**

when call `iptables -L` shows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something outside your control is blocking port 81. Use Name Based virtual hosting and/or a reverse proxy on port 80 instead.

---

Your firewall us blocking connections to port 81. You will need to INSERT a rule into your INPUT table to open the port. You should take a look at the documentation for [iptables](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html)(1). I'm sure you'll find plenty of hep on SF and the wider internet too is you search.

Comment: actually what I first did is modify iptable config file and add an INPUT rule for port 81 right below the rule for port 80. But it still failed, so I tried to close iptable and try again. The wired thing is it still failed then.

Comment: You have either misconfigured iptables or something between the external machine and your server is blocking the port. Show us the output of `iptables -L INPUT -vn`

Comment: `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 697 packets, 56024 bytes)    
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination   `. Since I close iptables, there is no rule in iptables -L, right?

Comment: here outside means something related to ISP?